# how to translate django applications?

Tags: django

This question i am asking for one of my friend.

Recently he is trying to translate his django application into another language. He doesn't know how to do it?

How can we effectively use translation in django application?

How can we translate a django application into another language?

what are all the necessary steps for translating a django application into another language?

Is there any documentation available?

Thanks in advance........

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: Beside of tools like rosseta, "attranslate" is a modern tool that enables a semi-automated translation of Django apps: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [rosseta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta) this one can help you.

Comment: @sakeer it is not  foolish question, but it is a question that clearly shows lack of effort to answer it by yourself (i.e. googling it) thus the negative votes. Django comes with a out of the box translation system (called internationalization, or i18n for simplicity).